# Trigger AWS Step Function via Cloudwatch and pass some variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, aws-step-functions

a file in S3 bucket triggers cloud watch event ( I am able to capture the url and key via $.detail.xxxx

Code below

How can I then pass these to a step function and from step function pass them to fargate instance as an environment variable
trying to use terraform's "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" however, I cannot find good examples of launching and passing inputs to step function

Here is the full function i have so far

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "cw-target" {
 arn    = aws_sfn_state_machine.my-sfn.arn
 rule     = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.cw-event-rule.name
 role_arn = aws_iam_role.my-iam.arn

   input_transformer {
    input_paths = {
      bucket = "$.detail.requestParameters.bucketName"
    }
}
    input_template = <<TEMPLATE
        {
          "containerOverrides": [
             {
                "environment": [
                   { "name": "BUCKET", "value": <bucket> },
                 ]
             }
            ]
        }
  TEMPLATE
  }
```

on the cloudwatch event via the console I can see

```
{"bucket":"$.detail.requestParameters.bucketName"}
```

and

```
    {
          "containerOverrides": [
             {
            "environment": [
               { "name": "BUCKET", "value": <bucket> },
             ]
             }
            ]
    }
```

Just need to know how do I fetch this information inside the step function and then send it as ENV var when calling fargate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using input transformers in AWS eventbridge, check [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-input-transformer-tutorial.html).

You can transform the payload of the event to your liking into the step function by using an `InputPath` (as you have already done) and an `input template`, where you use variables defined in you InputPath to define a new payload. This new payload will be used as input for the step function.

Here are more examples of input paths and templates: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html

Edit:
If you want to start a fargate task with these environment variables, your best option is to indeed use the environment Overrides to specify new env variables on each task.

Old edit:
<strike>If you want to start a fargate task with these environment variables, you have two options:</strike>

1. Create a new task definition in you step function with the specified env vars, then start a new fargate task from this task definition.

2.only use 1 task definition created beforehand, and use env files in that task definition.  More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html). Basically what happens is when the task is started the task will fetch a file from s3 and use the values in that file as env vars. Then you step function only has to contain a step to upload a file to s3, en sten start a fargate task using the existing task definition.

Comment: Thank you!

I have updated the question to add a little more detail.
Tried to look at the article but it's not very clear to me how i fetch the information (updated in the question above) and pass it along to fargate

Comment: I added some info on that in my post. If you want to use only 1 task definition, use env var files. If you're ok with recreating task definitions, you can make that part of your step.function.

Comment: Thank you! in the case, If I already have a file in S3 how do you see the process being played?
Steps:
1. lambda creates a file in S3 with some important info                 
2. S3 triggers the cloudwatch rule             
3. Cloudwatch rule would start the step function (pass along the S3 files bucket name and file name)              
4. step function would then just pass the same file name and bucket name to the fargate                  
5. fargate can then download the file and get rest of the info inside it.

Comment: The env file in s3 needs to be a specific format as mentioned in the docs. The step function doesn't pass the file to the fargate task. It should already be a part of the task definition. The step function should just start the task with the previously mentioned task definition. This only works if the s3 bucket and key is not changing.  If it changes per run, you need to create a new task definition during each step function run.

Comment: oh boy, yes, the file name changes each time. okay thank you!